# Sending Jsch commands

Tags: java, linux, jsch

Beating my head against a wall here.
I am trying in the constructor to establish a link and log on.  Then in the begin method to execute a java application on the remote computer.  Finally in terminate, to kill the java process.

No exceptions show up, the command just doesn't execute.  I can see the user has logged in if I go to the remote terminal and run a last.  The user has only a login time of 0 though.  I can also get an error if I change the password to the wrong password.

But the remote java app isn't running.  Remote app runs fine when I log in directly from that terminal or ssh in and run it from the command line.

Ideas?  Thanks in advance.

```
//Constants for the login information
String HOST="<HOSTNAME>";
String USER="<userid>";
String PASSWORD="<password>";

//Constants for command strings
String START_COMMAND="java -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/share/OpenCV/java -jar <filename>";
String TERMINATE_COMMAND="killall java";

Channel channel;
Session session;
InputStream in;

public VisionProcessing(){
    java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties(); 
    config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    try {
        System.out.println("Trying login");
        session = jsch.getSession(USER, HOST, 22);
        session.setPassword(PASSWORD);
        session.setConfig(config);  //XXX No idea what this does
        session.connect();
        channel=session.openChannel("exec");
        ((ChannelExec)channel).setPty(true); 
        channel.connect();//This is important

        if (channel.isConnected()){
            System.out.println("Connected");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not Connected");
        }
    } catch (JSchException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Exception logging in");
    }
}

public boolean beginTargeting() {
    try {
        StringBuilder outputBuffer = new StringBuilder();

        Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
        InputStream commandOutput = channel.getInputStream();
        int readByte = commandOutput.read();

        while(readByte != 0xffffffff)
        {
           outputBuffer.append((char)readByte);
           readByte = commandOutput.read();
        }
        System.out.println("Begin");
    if (channel.isConnected()){
        System.out.println("Connected");            
        ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(START_COMMAND);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not Connected");
    }
    channel.connect();//This is important
    channel.disconnect();
    }catch(IOException ioX)
     {
        System.out.println(ioX);
     }
     catch(JSchException jschX)
     {
            System.out.println(jschX);
     }
    return true;
}



   public boolean terminateTargeting() {
    try {
    System.out.println("Terminate");
    channel=session.openChannel("exec");
    ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(TERMINATE_COMMAND);
    channel.connect();//This is important
    System.out.println("Terminating");

    channel.setInputStream(null);
    channel.disconnect();
    session.disconnect();
    System.out.println("DONE");
}catch(Exception ee){
    System.out.println(ee);
}
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What's a point of `channel=session.openChannel("exec");` in the constructor? Why do you call `setPty` for that channel and not for the others? Show us [mcve]! A simplest code possible!

Comment: My understanding of openChannel is that it invoked the ChannelExec class. The setPty I admit I don't know. I've been fiddling for a while and had put that in and out, I thought I'd taken it out everywhere.

Comment: But you never use the returned `ChannelExec` instance - Anyway, again, show us some simple example that reproduces your problem. A simple piece of code, no 3 methods.